# Convergence of a limit as in Abels theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Abels theorem makes a statement about the continuity of a convergent power series for $x<1$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$$
at $x=1$, that is if $f(1)$ exists, it equals $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-} f(x)$.

While it is fairly well known, isn't this more or less clear? I stop seeing why this is such a deal; I mean what else should it be, or are there counter-examples? Isn't it just that the continuity of $x^n$ translates to the sum, or do I missunderstand something?

Furthermore, why did he restrict his considerations to power series? Wouldn't the following argument apply to general series? Is there a name for it?

Suppose I have a sequence of continuous real functions $f_n(x)$ on $[0,1]$ and
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
converges for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$, which can be seen as follows. Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and split the sum at $n=N$
$$\left|f(1)-f(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(f_n(1)-f_n(x)\right)\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \left|f_n(1)-f_n(x)\right| + \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty f_n(1) \right| + \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty f_n(x)\right| \, .$$
Since the series converges for all $x\in[0,1]$, $N$ can be chosen s.t. the latter two terms are less than $\epsilon/3$. Having fixed $N$, we know that since $f_n(x)$ is continuous for all $n$, there exist $\delta_n>0$ s.t. for all $x\in[0,1]$ with $1-x<\delta_n$ we have that
$$\left|f_n(1)-f_n(x)\right| < \epsilon/3N \, .$$
Choosing a universal $\delta={\rm min}\{\delta_1,...,\delta_N\}$, it follows that for $1-x<\delta\leq \delta_n$
$$\left|f(1)-f(x)\right| < \sum_{n=1}^N\epsilon/3N + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon \, .$$

Comment: take $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{n-1}, n \ge 2, f_1(x)=x$; then $\sum_{k \le N}f_k(x)=x^N$ which converges to $0$ if $0 \le x <1$ and to $1$ if $x=1$ so the limit function $f$ is not continuous; good exercise - find what is wrong with your "proof" (maybe this counterexample gives you the hint)

Comment: Since you are not using $|x-1|<\delta$ and $1-x < \delta$ instead, what you are proving is the left continuity of the function (rather than continuity). But this is what Abel's theorem says! To say that $f$ is continuous at $x=1$, we should also have some control over how $f$ behaves for near $x>1$ too.

Comment: @Conrad: I think I can not change $N$ and $x$ independently. Once I fix $N$, I can not change $x$ anymore to manipulate the first term, because I would increase the last term again.

Comment: correct - uniform convergence indeed gives a continuous result and that is well known from topology; Abel theorem though is different, one has power series but needs only pointwise convergent at the endpoint

Comment: What do you mean by "known from topology". Known as what? But wouldn't this result prove Abel's theorem? If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is finite, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ for $x<1$. In particular you could find $N$ s.t. $$\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n x^n\right| < \epsilon/3$$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Or do you have another exotic example which contradicts this?^^

Comment: Uniform convergence of a series of continuous functions (precisely the condition you need so you can switch $N,\delta$) implies that the sum is continuous - this is true for any metric space and continuous functions from there to the complex numbers say and is a well known topological result; in the Abel case we have uniform convergence only on compact subsets of $[0,1)$ but not near $1$ in general, however the result holds because of the specific form of power series; as for your last claim, that again holds obviously if $a_n$ is absolutely convergent only

Comment: So Abels theorem basically says that, if a power series is uniformly convergent on any compact subset of $[0,1)$ and if it is finite at $x=1$, then it is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$? So for my "last claim" I would have to use Abels theorem so to say?

Comment: If the power series $\sum a_nx^n$ is convergent at $1$ (so $\sum a_n$ converges) automatically $a_n \to 0$ so it has radius of convergence at least $1$ hence it is normally (absolutely and locally uniformly) convergent on $|x|<1$; then yes, Abel's theorem says that it is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$; more generally one can extend this uniform convergence to Stolz domains inside the unit disc (essentially triangles inside the unit disc with a vertex at $1$ and acute angles on either side of the radius from $0$ to $1$)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is wrong.  For example, let $f_n$ be the piecewise-linear function on $[0,1]$
$$ f_n(x) = \cases{0 &  for  $0 \le x \le 1/(n+1)$\cr
  n (n+1) x - n & for $1/(n+1) \le x \le 1/n$\cr
 - n (n-1) x + n & for $1/n \le x \le 1/(n-1)$\cr} $$
Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = 1$ for $0 < x \le 1$, but $0$ for $x = 0$.